# Converting large volume Excel Data into XML in Java

Tags: java, excel, xml

Consider we have an Excel file with 4 columns:

```
|ID|Value1|Value2|Value3|
|Fruits|Apple|Banana|Papaya|
|Cars|Mercedes|Ferrari|Haas|
```

There can be million of rows in the Excel file.

From the Excel file, We need to read the values row by row and create an XML.

Problem:
I am allowed to code in a method like `valueAddition(String value, int row, int col)` where we will be getting the values row-wise.

I am thinking of a solution where we will be creating a Map, to store all the values from the Excel file to the memory and then create the XML traversing the values in the variable (memory).

There is no option to create the XML file while iterating `valueAddition()` because the XML file may be in this format:

```xml
    <Values>
        <ValueList ID="Fruits">
            <Value>Apple</Value>
            <Value>Banana</Value>
            <Value>Papaya</Value>
        </ValueList>
        <Valueist ID="Cars">
            <Value>Mercedes</Value>
            <Value>Haas</Value>
            <Value>Haas</Value>
        </ValueList>
    </Values>
```

Where I won't be knowing while the control will be in `valueAddition()`, that the same Fruits ID can be present in the last part of the Excel File and I need to map it inside the XML tag `<ValueList ID="Fruits">`.

Now putting records of millions in memory can be troublesome. Is there any alternative method to do it?

Please Note:
`XSSFReader` (Apache POI) is used to read the Excel file row-wise.
The `valueAddition(String value, int row, int col)` method will be called in a loop...
At a time, the `valueAddition` will contain the value in the Excel file, the row number, and its column number.

For example,

```java
    valueAddition("Fruits", 1, 0)
    valueAddition("Apple", 1, 1)
    valueAddition("Banana", 1, 2)
    valueAddition("Papaya", 1, 3)
    valueAddition("Cars", 2, 0)
    valueAddition("Mercedes", 2, 1)
```

The definition of the `valueAddition` method was not done yet... the thought process is that each value will be stored in a map variable such as

```java
    class Values {
        String value1;
        String value2;
        String value3;
    }

    Map<String,Values) valuesWithId = new HashMap<>();

    valueAddition(String value, int row, int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            valuesWithId.put(value, null);
        else {
            // append the values to the corresponding value in the Map.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you talk about a native excel file (format) or a CSV file? What does method "ValueAddition()" do? Can you provide some example code what you have tried so far?

Comment: can the same id appear in more than one line?

Comment: Yes the same ID can appear in more than one line.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/XMLPG/stax.htm